# Is it possible to capture python gdb variables into the value history?

Tags: python, c, gdb

I have a [python gdb](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Python-API.html#Python-API) script which writes to `gdb.STDOUT`, and I'd like to capture this value into the [value history](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Value-History.html#Value-History) or a [convenience variable](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html#Convenience-Vars) so that it's easily referenced.

For example, this script iterates a linked list and dumps the output:

```
(gdb) list MY_OBJECT Links myObjectList 4
(MY_OBJECT *) 0x80f830198
{ReferenceCount = 1, Flags = 0, Mutex = {Mutex = 0x80f80fe50, State = 1}, Links = {Next = 0x81182f138, Prev = 0x80f80f5a8}}
(MY_OBJECT *) 0x81182f0d8
{ReferenceCount = 6, Flags = 0, Mutex = {Mutex = 0x811815790, State = 1}, Links = {Next = 0x81182f1f8, Prev = 0x80f8301f8}}
(MY_OBJECT *) 0x81182f198
{ReferenceCount = 2, Flags = 0, Mutex = {Mutex = 0x811816830, State = 1}, Links = {Next = 0x80f8302b8, Prev = 0x81182f138}}
(MY_OBJECT *) 0x80f830258
{ReferenceCount = 1, Flags = 0, Mutex = {Mutex = 0x80f8528e0, State = 1}, Links = {Next = 0x80f80f5a8, Prev = 0x81182f1f8}}
```

Is it possible to write to the gdb value history?  Maybe through `gdb.parse_and_eval()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out through experimentation that you can execute gdb commands directly from a python api command, and they will be captured into the value history.

So instead of using `gdb.write("%s" % myObject)` or `print` from python, one can instead do `gdb.execute("print %s" % myObject)`  which gives the desired side effect.

```
(gdb) list MY_OBJECT Links myObjectList 4
$1 = {ReferenceCount = 1, Flags = 0, Mutex = {Mutex = 0x80f80fe50, State = 1}, Links = {Next = 0x81182f138, Prev = 0x80f80f5a8}}
$2 = {ReferenceCount = 6, Flags = 0, Mutex = {Mutex = 0x811815790, State = 1}, Links = {Next = 0x81182f1f8, Prev = 0x80f8301f8}}
$3 = {ReferenceCount = 2, Flags = 0, Mutex = {Mutex = 0x811816830, State = 1}, Links = {Next = 0x80f8302b8, Prev = 0x81182f138}}
$4 = {ReferenceCount = 1, Flags = 0, Mutex = {Mutex = 0x80f8528e0, State = 1}, Links = {Next = 0x80f80f5a8, Prev = 0x81182f1f8}}

(gdb) print &$1
$5 = (MY_OBJECT *) 0x80f830198
```